# How to ensure latest file is served by the server, when client makes a request for that file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, web

when I make request for getting a file ex. JSON file, the browser is taking file from its cache even if I modify file at the server.

```
$(".button3").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "app/defaultLabelJSON.json",
        context: document.body
    });
  });
```

I found that there is Etag appended by IIS. This allows the server to identify if the cached contents of the resource are different to the most recent version.
But in my case it is not working even if Etag is present.

[image: Browser Request Log]

Is there any other solution available for this other than adding ?versionString with the request?

Comment: Try adding a random integer to the query string. Like this: app/defaultLabel,json?n=14242. Take a look at how to generate a random number in JS and append it to the URL, every time you make a request.

Comment: use the cache parameter : `cache: false`. Refs : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/